How to resize a LUKS partition?
To put it simply, I'm trying to resize the /sdb3 partition to about 500gb, then use the rest of the space on the drive as an ntfs partition. In gparted it only lets me free up 32mb of space. I have no idea how to get this to work.



Backup everything (to a different /disk/device/cloud/whatever) and verify it
resize2fs /dev/dm-0 NEW_SIZE
cryptsetup-resize --size SIZE_IN_512B_SECTORS NAME
cryptsetup CLOSE NAME
sfdisk /dev/sdb > sbd.txt
vi sdb.txt (adjust accordingly)
sfdisk /dev/sdb < sbd.txt

You can and you will make a ton of mistakes and destroy your data in the process. A much better option would be to backup your data, verify the backup, delete the partition, create a new one, restore your data.
